# Why don't virtual particles violate conservation of mass/energy?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy-conservation, feynman-diagrams, virtual-particles

If virtual particles sometimes add more mass/energy to a system then was inputed or comes out in the output, how do they not violate conservation of mass/energy.

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68235/58382

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. *Virtual particles are not real.* Though sounding like a tautology, it is an important one - they are not actual states in the asymptotic Hilbert spaces of a quantum field theory, where particles usually live. They are a *name* given to *internal lines* of [Feynman diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram), which, in turn, are mere computational tools in a perturbative approach to QFT. *Nothing* in the formalism itself justifies imbuing these lines or diagrams with any more meaning, so it is unclear what it means to say *"virtual particles sometimes add more mass/energy to a system"* as you do in the question.
2. Conservation of energy holds, quantumly, only inside correlation functions and up to contact terms - the quantum version of [Noether's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem), which classically guarantees conservation of energy, are the [Ward-Takahashi identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward%E2%80%93Takahashi_identity). Even *if* the internal lines of Feynman diagrams represent particles in any sense, conservation of energy/momentum is only guaranteed to hold as a statement about *expectation values*, so that individual states may well, from a classical viewpoint "violate conservation of energy". (Note, though, that "energy of a state" may even be an ill-defined thing to say)

Comment: You said "Virtual particles are not real", being internal lines of Feynman diagrams. But the electron (for instance) that is detected can then be considered as an internal line of a bigger Feynman diagram including the detector. I know that this debate has been open many times, but I don't find satisfying answer to this point. (the usual answer consists in saying that a single Feynman diagram is meaningless, all the higher orders contributing to the process. yes. But it just shifts the problem: what we usually call an electron would be simply be the global contribution).

Comment: (con't) in addition, even in orthodox quantum mechanics, an electron can be slightly off-shell (living a finite time between its creation and its destruction), which is considered usually as a degree of virtuality.

Comment: @Paganini: Feynman diagrams are a way of organizing perturbation theory because we are too dumb to solve the exact theory. It is meaningless to say that a real particle "can be considered as an internal line, because the internal line is not a quantum state, while a real particle is. The possible slight off-shellness of real particles is explained by my point 2 - the quantum theory obeys classical laws only on average.

Comment: yes, but considering external lines as pure quantum state is also an approximation no? It assumes pure free particles without interaction at all, which is only approximative too.

Comment: @Paganini: Of course. Unfortunately, the Hilbert space of interacting QFTs is unknown except for very special cases.