# If virtual particles violate for a little moment the conservation of energy, can energy be created?

Tags: energy, vacuum, virtual-particles

And if that is the case, can an infinite amount of it be created? Does this mean that the potential energy or the energy that can potentially be created is infinite?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Virtual Photon in Electron Scattering Feynman diagram](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/294177/)

Comment: And [Why don't virtual particles violate conservation of mass/energy?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/168845/)

Comment: I think the OP asks for the reasons of the (im)possibility of some similar thing like a Maxwell-demon, but with quantum fluctuations (and not with thermical fluctuations). The dupe candidates, although they are similar questions, don't point into this direction and also not their answers. Thus, I vote for "leave open".

Comment: please see my answer here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/185110/do-virtual-particles-actually-physically-exist . A virtual particle can only exist as a mathematical expression under an intergral, in interactions with real particles, which carry the energy and momentum conservation. The vacuum has zero energy and thus the vacuum loops are not calculable. Only within a real interaction can virtual particles "exist".